# Pipeline issues in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a neural network model which I wish to fit to my training data.  When I compile the below line of code

```
history = pipeline.fit(inputs[train], targets[train], epochs=epochs, batchsize=batchsize)
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Pipeline.fit does not accept the epochs parameter. You can pass parameters to specific 
steps of your pipeline using the stepname__parameter format, e.g. 
`Pipeline.fit(X, y, logisticregression__sample_weight=sample_weight)`
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post a [mre]; it is impossible to know how an `epochs` parameter might be involved here with the information (not) provided.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the `epochs` parameter is defined for `MLPClassifier`; you should use the `max_iter` parameter instead.

Then if you want to specify hyperparameters within a `Pipeline`, you can do as follows:

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer    

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification


X, y = make_classification()


model = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(), StandardScaler(), MLPClassifier())

params = {
    'mlpclassifier__max_iter' : 10,
    'mlpclassifier__batch_size' : 20
}

model.set_params(**params)
model.fit(X, y)
```

I would suggest using this notation as you can easily reuse it to perform a `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: Thank you, Antoine.  Is there a way to include "impute" in the pipeline?  I have a dataset with several NaN values, so I have to get rid of these via imputation.

Comment: I added `SimpleImputer` to my example.

Comment: Hi Antoine, I tried your example.  But, somehow, it does not work.  I am not able to decode the following error message. 

"X has 14 features, but SimpleImputer is expecting 20 features as input."

The input X has 14 features in my dataset, but I am not able to understand why SimpleImputer expects 20 features.