# What is the best practice to chain DL model into sklearn Pipeline() stages and still access hyperparameters e.g, batch_size \ epochs in pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, hyperparameters

I want to experiment DL regression model over time-series data by implementing the model using [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) [`pipeline()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline) properly. I formed the following DL model in the form of the  `class WaveNet` and would like to call it within the pipeline accordingly.

```py
#Model definition
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Activation, Add, Multiply,Lambda, Convolution1D, Dense, Dropout
from keras.initializers import TruncatedNormal

class WaveNet:
    def __init__(self, timesteps, dilation_depth=9, n_filters=32):
        self.timesteps = timesteps
        self.dilation_depth = dilation_depth
        self.n_filters = n_filters
        self.model = self._build_model()

    def _build_model(self):
        # Define the input layer
        input_layer = Input(shape=(self.timesteps, 1))

        # Define the residual blocks
        skip_connections = []
        x = input_layer
        for i in range(self.dilation_depth):
            # Define the dilation rate
            dilation_rate = 2 ** i
            
            # Define the residual block
            tanh_out = Convolution1D(self.n_filters, 3, activation='tanh',    padding='causal', dilation_rate=dilation_rate)(x)
            sigm_out = Convolution1D(self.n_filters, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='causal', dilation_rate=dilation_rate)(x)
            x = Multiply()([tanh_out, sigm_out])
            skip_connections.append(x)

        # Define the skip connection layer
        summed = Add()(skip_connections)
        out = Activation('relu')(summed)

        # Define the output layers
        out = Convolution1D(1, 1, activation='linear', padding='same')(out)
        out = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -1, :])(out)
        out = Dense(1, kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(stddev=0.01))(out)

        # Define the model and compile it
        model = Model(input_layer, out)
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

        return model

    def summary(self):
        self.model.summary()


#build an end-to-end pipeline, and supply the data into a regression model and train within the pipeline.
#Train and fit the WaveNet model into the pipeline chain
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline

WaveNetRegressor = WaveNet(timesteps=5, dilation_depth=9, n_filters=32)
WNet_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),('WNet', WaveNetRegressor())]).fit(X_train, y_train) #X, y
```

And get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-9c90503b7a90> in <cell line: 94>()
     92 
     93 WaveNetRegressor = WaveNet(timesteps=5, dilation_depth=9, n_filters=32)
---> 94 WNet_pipeline = Pipeline([('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),('WNet', WaveNetRegressor())]).fit(X_train, Y_train) #X, y
     95 
     96 #Displaying a Pipeline with a Preprocessing Step and Regression

TypeError: 'WaveNet' object is not callable
```

I checked related posts, and they offer **wrapper** for non-[sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) models to integrate into [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) pipeline, but I couldn't figure out to implement it so far. I also couldn't figure out how to access important hyperparameters e.g, `batch_size` or `epochs` within **pipeline** during training (the model itself has some hyper-parameters as well):

Wrapper for [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) pipeline:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47520976/10452700

here they used *model function* `def model`, not `class model` by using `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn` and no info if we need to manipulate and set hyper-parameters. Maybe there is an elegant way to use the class and access hyper-parameters too:

```py
# wrap the model using the function you created
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor, KerasClassifier
reg = KerasRegressor(build_fn=reg_model, verbose=0)

# just create the pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('reg',reg)]).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69171762/10452700

Access the learning hyperparameters within the pipeline:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75263781/10452700

Here they used [`make_pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline) not [`Pipeline()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline)

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70335732/10452700

---

Edit: `WaveNetRegressor` instead of `WaveNetRegressor()`

```py
....
WNet_pipeline = Pipeline([('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),('WNet', WaveNetRegressor)]).fit(X_train, Y_train) #X, y
...
```

get as follow:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-077fd9956e62> in <cell line: 94>()
     92 
     93 WaveNetRegressor = WaveNet(timesteps=5, dilation_depth=9, n_filters=32)
---> 94 WNet_pipeline = Pipeline([('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),('WNet', WaveNetRegressor)]).fit(X_train, Y_train) #X, y
     95 
     96 #Displaying a Pipeline with a Preprocessing Step and Regression

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    399         """
    400         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 401         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    402         with _print_elapsed_time("Pipeline", self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
    403             if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    337         # shallow copy of steps - this should really be steps_
    338         self.steps = list(self.steps)
--> 339         self._validate_steps()
    340         # Setup the memory
    341         memory = check_memory(self.memory)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _validate_steps(self)
    241             and not hasattr(estimator, "fit")
    242         ):
--> 243             raise TypeError(
    244                 "Last step of Pipeline should implement fit "
    245                 "or be the string 'passthrough'. "

TypeError: Last step of Pipeline should implement fit or be the string 'passthrough'. '<__main__.WaveNet object at 0x7f458634ea90>' (type <class '__main__.WaveNet'>) doesn't
```

Answer (score 0):

`WaveNet` is a class, but `WaveNetRegressor` is an *instance* of that class.  So in your pipeline, you should put `WaveNetRegressor`, not `WaveNetRegressor()`.  (Those parentheses are the source of the error: you appear to be trying to use the instance as a "callable".)

I won't go into each of your linked questions for now, except to say that `make_pipeline` is a convenience function that returns a `Pipeline` whose steps are named automatically.  Ultimately there is no difference in functionality.

Comment: Please find and check the update on my post with its error.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I already attempted `WaveNetRegressor` instead of `WaveNetRegressor()`, I followed *end-2-end pipeline* [example](https://stackabuse.com/bytes/end-to-end-random-forest-regression-pipeline-with-scikit-learn/). Moreover, by your explanation, I ensure that there is **no** functionality difference between sklearn [`pipeline()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline) and [`make_pipeline()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline)

Comment: What is the best practice to call the model class within Pipeline using a wrapper?

Comment: I'm not as familiar with keras and sklearn interactions, and so whether it's better to add a `fit` method (and `predict`, and ...?) to your custom class, or to use `KerasRegressor`.  [Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70449758/10495893) that uses a grid search over `KerasRegressor`, maybe that's helpful?